# Rocketbot don't recognize the gdrive module folder

Tags: rpa

I am learning to use Rocketbot and I don't know how to fix this error.
I downloaded the module from [marketplace](https://market.rocketbot.co/?6#/module/gdrive) and it's in the Rocketbot modules folder and I don't know why it can't find it

Any suggestion? pls

[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA4Ge.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run Rocketbot from the containing folder, not from a shortcut.

In Windows go to **Rocketbot/** and execute

```
rocketbot.exe
```

In Mac go to **Rocketbot Folder** from terminal, ex.

```
cd /Users/User/Desktop/Rocketbot
./rocketbot_mac
```